# Why is window.innerWidth larger than window.outerWidth in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, window, size

In my Chrome browser, the page below gives

```
window.innerWidth 2133
window.outerWidth 1600
```

My screen resolution is only 1600x900, and in any case innerWidth > outerWidth. Why is this happening??

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
</head>
    <body>
        <textarea id="text" rows=10 cols=80>
        </textarea>

        <script>
            var s = ""
            s += "window.innerWidth " + window.innerWidth + "\n"
            s += "window.outerWidth " + window.outerWidth + "\n"
            document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = s
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: does this happen only on chrome? it could be due to an extension adding elements making the width bigger, try it in incognito window

Comment: The `html` at Question is invalid. `<body>` element is not valid permitted content of [`<head>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head) element.

Comment: @guest271314 moving the `<body>` made no difference for me, I was not able to replicate the problem

Comment: @Mohamed-Ted Cannot reproduce, here, as well plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/h6aB6FZwaRH36ClCXWzD?p=preview

Comment: I fixed the example so that head is in its proper place. After shutting down and restarting the computer the problem disappeared. I now get the expected
    window.innerWidth 1600
    window.outerWidth 1600
corresponding to my screen resolution. Seems to be some state kept in the browser, very weird. I'll get back if I see this again and can reproduce.